# Pass data from child view to parent view - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have two controller classes A and B. A instantiates several of B. When the appropriate button is pressed in A, A instantiates a B and program flow is passed to B. At the end of B's run I want it to pass some data back to A. How is this possible?

To be more precise, I have an NSArray of Objects, which I would like to return to 'A' after B runs its last method...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of options:

1. Keep your data in a singleton DataManager object that both VCs can reference
2. Have B post an NSNotification that it is done, and have A be an observer for that notification, pass the data of interest in the notification.
3. Give B a reference to an iVar in A so it can directly set the values
4. Give B a reference to a method in A (possibly by declaring a protocol) so it can call that method and pass the data base that way.

Probably more, but these are the ones I use most often.

Comment: Hi can you give an example of using protocol?

Comment: Here's a good place to start: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Protocol.html

Answer (score 1):

As Ray says, there are a number of ways, but the simplest is to pass an instance of `A` as an argument to `B`'s initializer, and then just call `A.whatever(...)` to pass the data back. It's probably easiest to define and use the `whatever(...)` method as an informal protocol - you know it exists, and the two modules know it exists, but there's nothing specific in the code that requires it to exist.

If you want to have a way of declaring that `B` will need an object to call back to and to specify what that object must be able to do, you could set up a formal protocol. This would say that you will need an object, not necessarily an `A`, but any object, that conforms to `MyBCallbackProtocol`, which you define as needing to have the one instance method of `whatever(...)`. The formal protocol lets the compiler check that the object you pass in definitely supports the method call you want.

It's probably overkill for this situation - but if the communication between `A` and `B` becomes more complex, you might want to use it to be sure that you've implemented all the methods that you've decided you need. If A is changed, the protocol helps to ensure that `B` will still be able to pass back its information.

NSNotificationCenter may be overkill as well if `A` and `B` are very specific to your app. It does, however, completely isolate `B` while allowing others to get data from it; if `B` is meant to be a reusable utility class, it's worth considering.

I would not pass in a reference to an ivar in A; this is getting B way too involved in A's business.

Answer (score 0):

There is a few way to accomplish that, the easiest and fastest solution is to use NSNotificationCenter. With NSNotificationCenter you can subscribe and send custom notifications.

NSNotificationCenter: 
Receive

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didFinishParsing:) name:@"yourNoticationName" object:nil];
- (void)didFinishParsing:(NSNotification *)aNotification {...}
```

Send

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"some", @"optional", @"data", @":)" nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"yourNoticationName" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
```